# Spaces in between Text

Tags: css

I have a question about putting a space between some text in CSS.
e.g

```
header #Project{
    float: left;
}

aside #sidebar{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Here the code above works perfectly fine, but the one on the bottom doesn't and the reason is the space between "aside" and "#sidebar". Why is that and how can I tell the difference?
Thx in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Its a CSS selector, mean that you are selecting the ***aside*** tag with ***sidebar*** Id.
Then the CSS within the body only for those selectors.

**Also you have missed the closed curly bracket**

```
aside #sidebar{
float: right;
width: 30%; }
```

Comment: also, if you have an aside tag with an id of 'sidebar' (ex, <aside id='sidebar'>, your really only need to use the id in your css, (i.e., you can change 'aside #sidebar' to just '#sidebar' in your css rule). There are other chars that can be entered between the 2 selector, that will alter your selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don´t understand the difference between those codes above. They are both semantics with an ID right? Why does the <aside> tag get treated differently than the <header> tag?

Comment: Actually both <header> and <aside> tags are semantic Elements, Its mean both define the meaning what they will contains, other than that <div> and <span> are Non-Semantic Elements. aside Contents defines some content aside from the original content like sidebar and header defines the content will show in the header like navigation, Its HTML 5 specification. you can also use div instead of these both. or any other non-semantic element.